# Android Program is running slow

Tags: android, firebase

I developed a firebase app, where one could post and you could like and react. Then, I stopped working on it. After some time, I started working on it again, when I was working on it, I found that the app now runs very slow, I had 3 layout (fragment used) and view pager added to it via adapter(before). Beforehand it used to work like a charm, but now when I move from one activity to other, the mobile device kind of like hangs. It was not behaving like this previously, why is that? Anyone facing similar problem?

Comment: do you have pictures in it? how many posts are you loading at once?

Comment: You are more than likely doing to much work on the UI thread.

Comment: all off them are on UI thread.... But it used to work like charm, before.. There is much lesser post to load than previous because I deleted manually from the Firebase... Also, I am using recyclerview so it wont take much space either, I reckon .

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would propose you allocate a larger memory to your ADB virtual device.

If this doesn't help, use Android Profiler to better understand the cause of this memory loss.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your AVD device settings and disable Device frame, this will improve the speed of your emulator

[image]

Comment: what phone are you using then ?

Comment: Samsung J1.. SDK 19.. It used to work before... Trust me, it used to work very well and now whenever I swipe, the image doesnt load properly either, though I have used Picasso Offline as well, and it doesnt show that image properly either